# list full details from files in folders and sub folder in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a document register which will in the end list certain files within a chosen folder and all sub folders, currently I have the code which is below which lists the files and their path. Though I can't think about what I need to add to this code to get the excel sheet to create a column which lists the file type "PDF","TXT",DWG" etc. Then another column which uses a predefined list to show what type of file these are (i.e. pdf=document, DWG=CAD file etc.).

The next thing I want to add is then a hyperlink which is generated from the path column.

Finally is there a way in which I can make excel ignore previously collected data, as the folder which the data will be collected from is updated regularly and I would like to be able to just run the VBA so it will ignore sub folders which is has already pulled data from.

Any help would be most appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
'the first row with data
Const ROW_FIRST As Integer = 5

'This is an event handler. It exectues when the user
'presses the run button
Private Sub btnGet_Click()
'determines if the user selects a directory
'from the folder dialog
Dim intResult As Integer
'the path selected by the user from the
'folder dialog 
Dim strPath As String
'Filesystem object
Dim objFSO As Object
'the current number of rows
Dim intCountRows As Integer
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Title = _
"Select a Path" 
'the dialog is displayed to the user
intResult = Application.FileDialog( _
msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
'checks if user has cancled the dialog
If intResult <> 0 Then
strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker _
).SelectedItems(1)
'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'loops through each file in the directory and prints their
'names and path
intCountRows = GetAllFiles(strPath, ROW_FIRST, objFSO)
'loops through all the files and folder in the input path
Call GetAllFolders(strPath, objFSO, intCountRows)   
End If
End Sub

'''
'This function prints the name and path of all the files
'in the directory strPath
'strPath: The path to get the list of files from
'intRow: The current row to start printing the file names
'in
'objFSO: A Scripting.FileSystem object.

Private Function GetAllFiles(ByVal strPath As String, _
ByVal intRow As Integer, ByRef objFSO As Object) As Integer
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
i = intRow - ROW_FIRST + 1
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'print file name
    Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 1) = objFile.Name
    'print file path
    Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 2) = objFile.Path
    i = i + 1
Next objFile
GetAllFiles = i + ROW_FIRST - 1
End Function

'''
'This function loops through all the folders in the
'input path. It makes a call to the GetAllFiles
'function. It also makes a recursive call to itself
'strFolder: The folder to loop through
'objFSO: A Scripting.FileSystem object
'intRow: The current row to print the file data on
Private Sub GetAllFolders(ByVal strFolder As String, _
ByRef objFSO As Object, ByRef intRow As Integer)
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objSubFolder As Object

'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
'loops through each file in the directory and
'prints their names and path
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
intRow = GetAllFiles(objSubFolder.Path, _
    intRow, objFSO)
'recursive call to to itsself
Call GetAllFolders(objSubFolder.Path, _
    objFSO, intRow)
Next objSubFolder
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** Make the following changes in `Function GetAllFiles` - it works for me:

After `Dim i As Integer`, add:

```
Dim Extension As String
```

After `Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 2) = objFile.Path`, add:

```
Extension = Right(objFile.Path, Len(objFile.Path) - InStrRev(objFile.Path, "."))
Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 3) = Extension
Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 4) = objFile.Type
Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 5).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & objFile.Path & """,""Link"")"
```

**Explanation:** The `Extension` variable is populated by looking for a dot `.` in the filename and only using what is right of the dot. This is then added to the next column. The description of that extension is taken from the file object's `Type` attribute. Lastly, the rightmost column is filled with the `=HYPERLINK` function pointing at the file and its path.

---

**Edit:** Edited after hint of @TimWilliams (thank you!), I simplified the above code. *If you need customized file type descriptions*, use the below approach instead and replace

```
Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 4) = objFile.Type
```

with

```
On Error Resume Next
Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Extension, _
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("filetypes").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
```

Before running this, you need to add one worksheet called **filetypes** and put the most common extensions in column A and their long text / explanation into column B:

[image]

To get a list like that without much work, you could copy what you find [on this website](http://fileinfo.com/filetypes/common), and just remove the dots `.` using the *Search & Replace* function.

Comment: Thanks this answers the hyperlink and file type part of my query. This has been very helpful. You wouldn't know how to ignore already listed files don't you?

Comment: Mmh, I am not sure I understand. If you select a folder and the macro lists all the files that are in it, how can there be duplicates?

Comment: FYI - a FileSystemObject `File` object has a property `Type`, which should return a description of the file - you may not need the lookup table